# Dynamic SQL Server query in Powerapps

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerapps

I have created a simple form in Powerapps which has a text input field called name and a data table which shows a list of all customers from a table called customer in a SQL Server database and I have also added a button labelled "Go" on the form.

What I want to do is:

1. See a blank data table when I first open the form
2. I would enter a customer name in the name text input field
3. Click the "Go" button and then the value from the name field will be passed to the SQL Server database in a query which only returns
   the records which have the same name
4. Display the results of the query in the data table.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Not familiar with PowerApps, but this blog seems to have everything you'd need to figure out a solution for your scenario: http://radacad.com/powerapps-building-timesheet-app-without-coding-part-3-connecting-to-multiple-data-source-and-getting-ready-to-build-dropdown-lists

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Its mainly how to trigger a dynamic SQL query part that I am struggling with but the blog doesn't seem to cover that

Comment: Does it have to use dynamic SQL given it's just a query against a user table?  Presumably you just need to pass the username as a parameter?  It looks like you may need Flow for that: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/PowerApps-Flow-SQL-Server-2012-Stored-Procedure-with-Parameters/td-p/110883 (sorry, not looked deeply as I've not touched PowerApps so aren't familiar enough to figure out what's useful)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll take a look.  I was hoping for it to be dynamic as the table could have millions of records on it and didn't want to pull them all into the table and then search

Comment: That's cool - you shouldn't need to use dynamic SQL if your SQL statement is the same but you're just changing the username that you're filtering on; you only need a username parameter for that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've been able to correctly add your on-premise SQL server as a data source:

You'll want to use a combination of Collect() and Filter()

Assign your user input to a variable using (this isn't strictly necessary)

`GetContext({UserVariable: TextInput.Text})`

Use a combination of Collect() to store the data you pull from MSSQL, and Filter() to, well, filter the data.

`Collect(AppStorageTable1, Filter('[dbo].SqlTable]', ColumnName1 = UserVariable))`

If you assign AppStorageTable1 as your data source for your data table, it should now appear. (Note, you'll have to declare/create it before it will appear as an option, but once you've used the name in Collect() it will appear as a data source).

**EDIT:** The term you likely were looking for is "delegable", a quick search will yield a few articles about it. The "Filter" function will pass the work off to your SQL server, so your app won't be responsible for processing/filtering the data.